# Delete column based on row value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet containing data. I want to delete the columns based on row value.

My code doesn't stop and when I hit escape, it has deleted all of the column from my starting columns.

I want to check values in row 2 from column D to the last used column (I have about 100 columns now) that if they contain C15, C17 and so on then don't do anything, else, delete the columns.

I only have 40k rows. My range, column and row will expand every week so I want to use VBA to cut down formatting time.

```
Sub test()
'start
Dim LR1 As Long
Dim i As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With ws
    LR1 = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim x
    arr = Array("C15", "C17", "C19", "C20", "C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25", "C28", "C29", "C30", "C32")

    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For i = LR1 To 4 Step -1
            If .Cells(2, i).Value = arr(x) Then
            Else
                .Columns(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    Next x
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: *1.* You have an extra `With ws` in the question. *2.* You never actually use the `With ws` - there should be periods in front of `Cells`, `Columns.Count`, and `Columns`. *3.* Delete starting from the rightmost column and moving left: `For i = LR1 to 4 Step - 1`. *4*. `Cells(2, i)`, not `Cells(2 & i)`.

Comment: thanks I tried to fix it and I have posted the revised codes but now my codes do nothing, meaning after I hit run macro, nothing happens

Comment: I think you missed point 2 - you're still not actually using the `With ws... End With`.

Comment: Sorry, am I not supposed to use 'with ws and end ws' or did I use it wrong. If I use it wrong, how to modify my codes

Comment: Add a period in front of `Cells` - twice - and `Columns` - once.

Comment: You also missed point 4.

Comment: Hi, can you re-check my codes I just revised it. Sorry I missed point 4 earlier. I don't think I am using with ws correctly since it's still does nothing when I run it.

Comment: You also have a typo - you have `LR` in your loop but `LR1` above it.

Comment: Thank you, yea I mis-spelled quite a bit now its back to endless loop where it doesn't stop and when I escape everything is deleted except column A-C

Comment: If you see something else, please let me know since we are back to square one. But at least the codes look much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides all the points made in the comments, the main issue is that your looping logic is off. Your outer loop should be the columns, and the inner loop should be the array. But with `Select Case` this can be simplified this to just one loop anyway.

Perhaps something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Dim lastCol As Long, i As Long
        Dim rng As Range

        lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = lastCol To 4 Step -1
            Select Case .Cells(2, i).Value
                Case "C15", "C17", "C19", "C20", "C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25", "C28", "C29", "C30", "C32"
                    ' keep
                Case Else
                    If rng Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng = .Columns(i)
                    Else
                        Set rng = Union(rng, .Columns(i))
                    End If
            End Select
        Next i

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know what's the main difference between yours and mine? Since your codes work great. Should I use range? Thank you

Comment: Your looping logic is off - your outer loop should be the columns, and the inner loop should be the array. But `Select Case` simplifies this to just one loop anyway.